# MVC3 Razor ViewBag.Model not making into the Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have modified a Model recently for a system I've inherited, and for some reason the ViewBag.Model is not making into the page.  I've reverted the code back to before I started tinkering, and still no luck.

The call into the view is as follows:

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(long id)
{
    var _news = _newsRepository.GetNewsById(id);
    ViewBag.Model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<News, NewsModel>(_news);
    ViewBag.Model.CurrentNewsImageFile = ConfigSettings.HostDomainName + ConfigSettings.NewsImageBasePath + _news.image_file;

    return View();
}
```

The view has the following code:

```
@model MyModels.Models.NewsModel

@{
    bool IsCreate = Model == null || Model.Id == 0;
    ViewBag.Title = IsCreate ? "Add News" : "Edit News";
}
```

The problem is that "Model" is always null in the view code... what have I missed?  Am I missing a fundamental here?

When tracing through the ActionResult code, right up until the `return View()` the debug inspector correctly shows the Model containing everything I would expect it too.

Comment: Have you debugged the automapper line to ensure its returning a mapped property?

Comment: The model doesn't go in the `ViewBag`; it gets passed straight into the `View()`.

Comment: `ViewBag` is not needed in your action, the model can be passed to the View(model) overload.

Comment: @Robert yes - the model in the viewbag contains everything I expect it too.

Comment: @anaximander & Charlie Brown I tried that - much of the inherited code follows this construct and it works - and it worked until I screwed something up that I traced through code for a few hours now and can't figure out what broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply return `View(theModel)`. If you don't pass the model into `View()` it doesn't know what to do.

However, I'm confused about the code you have listed, you seem to be trying to put the model into the ViewBag? The ViewBag shouldn't contain the model.

I think the code you want is:

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(long id)
{
    var _news = _newsRepository.GetNewsById(id);
    var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<News, NewsModel>(_news);
    model.CurrentNewsImageFile = ConfigSettings.HostDomainName + ConfigSettings.NewsImageBasePath + _news.image_file;

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Ok - this is weird - I had done this earlier, yet the page had the same error - and an almost identical section in another part of the application following the ViewBag.Model structure works (and still works).  This however, with the code above does indeed work now.  Be utterly stuffed as to why this is the case now, but thank-you.  Any ideas as to why this worked before and not now??

Comment: I think it is because in the view it just says `Model == null` instead of `ViewBag.Model == null`. 
But putting the model in the ViewBag makes no sense at all so stick with the suggested code! :)

Comment: Yeah - I thought that too - but the exact same code style works on another page in the app.  The previous vendor changed their coding style so often I have had to install a foam protector on my screen.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is the AutoMapper line. Once you have created your mappings I believe you need to them call them using the following syntax:

var newsModel = Mapper.Map(_news);